# How to show the drop down attribute value using getData() method in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, attribute-set, dropdown-attribute

When I try to get data from the material attribute like `$_product->getData('material')`, it shows the integer value. How can I convert it to the actual front-end value and in which file do I have to make the changes?.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of `getData()` you need to use `getAttributeText('attribute_code')` for dropdown attributes. like

```
$_product->getAttributeText('material');
```

For multi-select try this :

```
$result = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('material')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Comment: material has multi select values and it gives the values like 25,19,15 on 'getData()' where as getAttributeText('material') gives blank page on load

Comment: @Hemant, Check my updated answer once and let me know.

Comment: product->getResource() seems to be deprecated

Comment: Also, we should make sure that the custom attribute is set to be visible in its attribute property.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to get the "barcode" attribute but the result is "null", where is the mistake? $product->getAttributeText('barcode')

Answer (score 8):

You can get product attribute option values by below code

```
$_product->getAttributeText('material');
```

You can get multi select option values by

```
$_attributeValue = $block->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('sizing_guidelines')->getFrontend()->getValue($block->getProduct());
```

Comment: Sorry material has multi select values and it gives the values like 25,19,15

Comment: Try my updates answer

Comment: I tried it gives blank page

Comment: Have you got any solution for that and tell me which file in try to it.

Comment: i Am trying to get data in phtml template

Comment: which phtml file ?

Comment: In my custom module, I am searching the product and showing single product on page.

Answer (score 8):

To fetch value of attribute Use:

```
$this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('material');
```

Or

```
$this->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($this->getProduct()->getId(),'material',$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
```

Comment: product->getResource() seems to be deprecated

Comment: `$this->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($this->getProduct()->getId(),'material',$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());` works on v2.3.4-p1

Answer (score 3):

```
$_product->getAttributeText('material');
```

is the right answer --- beware that $_product->getResource() is a deprecated function

Answer (score 1):

The answers above were partially missing something (at least for my case, since I needed to use the custom attribute value inside the cart template), if you want to pass the custom attribute to a template proceed like this:

Create File catalog_attributes.xml inside /etc folder of any existing module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
     <attribute name="insert_here_your_attribute_code"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

and from inside the template, in case of attribute of type select

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $product->getAttributeText('attribute_code') ?>
```

where

```
$product = $block->getItem()->getProduct()
```

$block in this case was \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer

In case of attribute of type text instead

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $product->getCustomAttribute('attribute_code')->getValue() ?>
```

after that just execute

```
bin/magento c:c
```

And you should see the value of the custom attribute in your cart page or any other template files.

Comment: this is works to call catalog custom attribute value from quote item. thanks