# Magento 2 : Get Custom Attribute Value of Product

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, product-attribute, custom

I'm trying to get custom attribut from my product.
I tried various methods like below, but non of them worked.

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
            $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getId());
            $attr = $product->getAttributes();
            $test1 = $product->getData('metal_pads');
            $test2 = $product->getCustomAttribute('metal_pads');
            $test3 = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('metal_pads');
            $test4 = $ddd->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

I'm able to get the Interceptor, but not value.

*** edit *** 
I'm using a default value which is also not visible

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To fetch value of attribute Use:

First get Your Product Collection and then

```
$this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('attribute_text');

e.g: $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('metal_pads');
```

Or

```
$product = $this->getProduct();
$ressource = $product->getResource();
$store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();

$ressource->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(),'metal_pads',$store->getId());
```

You can check this question as reference:

[How to show the drop down attribute value using getData() method in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146175/how-to-show-the-dropdown-attibute-value-using-getdata-method-in-magento-2/146182#146182)

Hopefully, It will help you

Comment: Also  var_dump your product collection using get_class_methods(). You will find getMetalPads() methods if your attribute was correctly configured.

Comment: Both are not woking for me.

Comment: In which version you are working? @groy

Comment: Glad to know it :) sorry for late @SagarPPanchal

Comment: I am using Magento 2.2.5.
However https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231033/how-to-fetch-product-attribute-value-in-phtml-file-in-magento-2/266099#answer-266099 fixed issue.

Comment: it's working on phtml  but i want to get from checkout config jquery ?
how i can do this???

Comment: I can't retrieve the barcode attribute, result is "false": $product->getProduct()->getAttributeText('barcode')

Comment: @Silver if you already have $product object, you do not need to call getProduct() just use $product->getAttributeText('barcode')

Comment: Beware that this does retrieve the translated value, so if you're building logic on certain values you may have to keep that in mind

Answer (score 3):

You can get the product attribute value like this,

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load('YOUR PRODUCT ID');
echo $product->getMetalPads();
```

**NOTE** : Use of Objectmanager is not recommended, so you can use it by Block or Helper.

Comment: alwasy returns `null` maybe something is wrong with my config..

Comment: verify that you assign that attribute in proper attribute set and that attribute-set assign to your product.

Comment: I'm not using a product set, just added a new product attribut and assigned it to the product

Comment: Vefiry that you replace proper product_id in above code. Try to get product name, sku.

Comment: also on other product_ids I should at least get the default value

Comment: for the moment i'm ending up using raw queries, which works

Comment: Use of ObjectManager is not recommended.

Comment: Bad answer => Attention: DO NOT use objectManagert; DO NOT use model->load(), USE repository instead.