# How to fetch product attribute value in phtml file in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

How can I fetch custom product attribute value such as **size** when it's added to the cart?

I want to show the **size** selected in an add to cart popup `(which contains all product details)!`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do you mean, you want the value of selected option from page, right?

Answer (score 3):

Use below, it worked for me:

```
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$product = $block->getProduct();

echo $_attributeValue = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

Answer (score 0):

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$product->getCustomAttributeCode();`

Comment: Use of ObjectManager is not recommended in Magento 2. You can inject the class in constructor where required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$product->getData("attribute_code");
```