# how to get current products custom attribute value in block(phtml) to display in products details page magento2?

Tags: magento2, blocks, custom-attributes, product-view

> Here i am trying to get current products custom attribute value in
>   block(phtml) and after that i want to show these custom attributes
>   values in products details page using block,phtml file magento2.

Comment: Please check this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157584/magento-2-get-custom-attribute-value-of-product

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can get product from registry and then show it custom attribute value.

```
$OM =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$registry = $OM->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry'); 
$currentProduct = $registry->registry('current_product');

if($currentProduct)
{
   echo $currentProduct->getName() . '<br />';
   echo $currentProduct->getSku() . '<br />';
   echo $currentProduct->getCustomAttribute();
}
```

**NOTE:** ObjectManager is not recommended according to magento standard.

Comment: if we use this attribute code $currentProduct->getResource()->getAttribute('product_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($currentProduct); then it is working fine

Comment: Object Manager is never a good awnser

Comment: @Riccardo, Yes I know that one, check the question feasibility and if you know the better answer then give it as well.

Comment: Yes, @Riccardo. Please enlighten us with a better way.