# How to get the custom attribute of products from the cart?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, product-collection, quote, custom-attributes

There is an attribute in the product `AllowSameDayDelivery` how can I get it out of the product?

I got the products ids from the cart, But how do I get the attribute now?

```
<?php

namespace Ronis\SameDayDelivery\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class DayDelivery implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    protected $_cart;
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * [__construct description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context [description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory [description]
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/delivery.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $cartProductIds = $this->_cart->getQuoteProductIds();
        $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $productCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => [$cartProductIds]]);
        foreach ($productCollection as $item){
            var_dump ($item->getAllowSameDayDelivery());die;
        }
    }
}
```

> now it always returns null even though it is in this product.

Comment: possible as duplicate https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/157584/60921

Comment: use the flag action to mark it as duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the product collection you will get only product attributes with the flag **Used in Product Listing** set to **'yes'**.

Therefore you have two solutions:

1. Set the flag **Used in Product Listing** set to **'yes'** for your attribute `allow_same_day_delivery` (I guess that's your attribute_code)

or alternative

2. load the product by Id for each product in the foreach loop using the ProductFactory, then you have all attributes available

Comment: this is how I have yes values ​​in the product.
I downloaded the product by "_productCollectionFactory". How do I get my attribute now?

Comment: That depends on the type of your attribute: For text/varchar attributes `$item->getData('allow_same_day_delivery');` or `$item->getAllowSameDayDelivery()` should work. For select attributes you should be able to get the attribute text like this `$item->getAttributeText('allow_same_day_delivery');` But anyway if `$item->getData('allow_same_day_delivery');` is empty the attribute seems not to be in the collection

Comment: Not one of the options came up. All give out null, except for the last one, but they also give out not what is needed.

Comment: So `$item->getData('allow_same_day_delivery');` will get you some not empty / null output, but $item->getAttributeText('allow_same_day_delivery'); not? What kind of attribute is `allow_same_day_delivery`?

Comment: How then to add it to the collection?

Comment: This is an attribute, a checkbox, yes / no.

Comment: That depends if you have enabled flat collection or not. If you don't use flat collection you can add the attribute to the collection like `$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('allow_same_day_delivery')` - with flat enabled and the setting from my answer the attribute shoud be available

Comment: Here, added to the collection, now earned. $ Item-> getData ('allow_same_day_delivery');
Thank you very much