# How to get the product id based on custom attribute value?

Tags: magento2.2.2, custom-attributes

I have custom attribute value in my store.

How can I get the product id based on that custom attribute value?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch value of attribute Use:

First get Your Product Collection and then

```
$this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('attribute_text');

e.g: $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('capacity');
```

Or

```
$this->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($this->getProduct()->getId(),'capacity',$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
```

You can check this question as reference:

[How to show the dropdown attibute value using getData() method in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146175/how-to-show-the-dropdown-attibute-value-using-getdata-method-in-magento-2/146182#146182)

Hopefully, It will help you

Comment: Also var_dump your product collection using get_class_methods(). Will find getCapacity() methods if your attribute was correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

check **loadByAttribute** fucntion of product model **Magento\Catalog\Model\AbstractModel** class, it will give you idea how to get product id / object based on attribute code and value:

```
/**
 * Load entity by attribute
 *
 * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AttributeInterface|integer|string|array $attribute
 * @param null|string|array $value
 * @param string $additionalAttributes
 * @return bool|\Magento\Catalog\Model\AbstractModel
 */
public function loadByAttribute($attribute, $value, $additionalAttributes = '*')
{
    $collection = $this->getResourceCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
        $additionalAttributes
    )->addAttributeToFilter(
        $attribute,
        $value
    )->setPage(
        1,
        1
    );

    foreach ($collection as $object) {
        return $object;
    }
    return false;
}
```